# Is clearDepth(0) possible in Three.JS?

Tags: three.js

In order to estimate the thickness of a mesh, I set up two renderTargets for frontface and backface depth data. Convert the values in depth buffer to linear depths, and subtract back from front to get thickness.

In order to get the depth textures right, these should be set:

1. while rendering front depth texture:

   mesh.material.side = THREE.FrontSide, 
   mesh.material.depthFunc = THREE.LessEqualDepth;
   clearDepth (1);
   // ... clear to far plane 
   // ... saw this in the code, but don't know how to set it
2. while rendering back depth texture:

   mesh.material.side = THREE.BackSide, 
   mesh.material.depthFunc = THREE.GreaterEqualDepth;
   clearDepth (0); 
   // ... clear to NEAR plane 
   // ... never see this in the code!!

Is this not supported in three.js?

The code (animate) looks like this:

```
function animate() {

    controls.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.setClearColor (0xffff00);
    sphere.material.side = THREE.FrontSide;
    // sphere.material.depthFunc = THREE.LessEqualDepth;
    renderer.render (sceneRTT, cameraRTT, frontDepthTex, true);
    sphere.material.side = THREE.BackSide;
    //  sphere.material.depthFunc = THREE.GreaterEqualDepth;
    renderer.render (sceneRTT, cameraRTT, backDepthTex, true);

    renderer.render (scene, camera);
}
```

a "working" jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmcjc5u/n3yLfk8L/14/

The test model is a convex ellipsoid. Thus, I don't need to change the settings of depthFunc and clearDepth. But for general concave models, I believe they should be changed.

Comment: Is `renderer.state.buffers.depth.setClear( value );` what you want?

Comment: following your suggestion, I modified the code as follows. It does not work!! 
Then, I use " gl = renderer.context;" and use the GL commands directly. It works OK. 
What's the difference?     
  
 sph.material.side = THREE.FrontSide;
 sph.material.depthFunc = THREE.LessEqualDepth; 
 renderer.state.buffers.depth.setClear(1);
 renderer.render (sceneRTT, cameraRTT, frontDepthTex, true);
 
 sph.material.side = THREE.BackSide;
 sph.material.depthFunc = THREE.GreaterEqualDepth;
 renderer.state.buffers.depth.setClear(0);
 renderer.render (sceneRTT, cameraRTT, backDepthTex, true);

Comment: this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jmcjc5u/dwbdkuyw/) has these two versions...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set the depth used by `gl.clearDepth( value )` like so:

```
renderer.state.buffers.depth.setClear( value );
```

This will set the value written into the depth buffer when the depth buffer is cleared.

three.js r.78

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please remember to "accept" answers by clicking on the check mark. Thank you.